# JUnit oddity - expected number not specified by me

Tags: java, testing, junit

First time using JUnit and so far its been pretty good. In a test I am expecting a number to be 128. I specify this in the code as:

```
assertEquals(myclass.myVar(), 228);
```

However I get such an odd error from JUnit:

```
expected:<418> but was:<228>
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<418> but was:<228>
```

So the program is giving me the right output. Which I have checked without JUnit just to make sure. But the test is failing. Could anyone shed some light on where its getting the 418 number from? I've not specified it anywhere in the Junit test file at all.

TIA

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got your arguments the wrong way round. It should be:

```
assertEquals(expectedValue, actualValue);
```

So your test should be:

```
assertEquals(228, myclass.myVar());
```

At that point you'll get a more reasonable message - and then you need to work out why `myVar()` is actually returning 418 :)

Answer (score 3):

In `assertEquals`, the first argument is supposed to be the expected value and the second the tested value. So you should have written:

```
assertEquals(228, myclass.myVar());
```

And the output would have been:

```
expected:<228> but was:<418>
```

Note: It might be surprising if you come from testNG which uses the opposite convention.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answers provided which point out that your values are backwards, you may look into using the newer JUnit notation:

```
assertThat(myclass.myvar(), is(228));
```

which puts the arguments in the more natural order and reads more fluently.